# Following messages of a user in telegram group

Tags: telegram

I need to get notified whenever a user posts a new message in a large telegram group. 
What is the best way to do that?
Is there any ready bot or method for this?
for example can I make a new channel which its posts are posts of that user?

Answer (score 0):

What you've to do is to listen to incoming message updates from that chat(group) -> Filter only these sent by the user -> forward that message to a specific channel.

Here is a working sample code in [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

API_ID = ...
API_HASH = " ... "

BOT_TOKEN = " ... "

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH).start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(
    chats=" ... ",  # insert group username here
    from_users=" ..."  # insert a user to monitor here
))
async def _(event):
    await event.message.forward_to(" ... ") # insert the username for the receiver chat/channel

with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

You can find the `API_ID` and `API_HASH` values from https://my.telegram.org.

Also [read telethon's Documentation here](https://docs.telethon.dev) if you wish to add/modify the behavior.