# Telethon telegram client: how to update the users list in chat from_users automatically?

Tags: asynchronous, client, telegram, telethon

I follow the example in [Following messages of a user in telegram group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62250687/following-messages-of-a-user-in-telegram-group), to forward users messages to another channel with a bot.

In

> from_users=" ...

I managed to get it working by giving it a list of telegram id/ usernames. And I now want to make it get the id/ usernames from a .txt file so that the "targets" would update automatically.

Now I built a function of fileToList that returns a list of id from the file.

However, I can't seem to add to anywhere to get it working automatically. I think it's because when events.NewMessage is defined, it kind of just stuck there.